# CheckMK 2.1 - Missing Export to JSON

Tags: check-mk

I've updated CheckMK from 2.0 to 2.1 and seems like the graph_export.py view has been removed.
I used it to get grapha json data.

From interface, the export options is missing too (image from 2.0).

[image]

I've read something about an endpoint in OpenAPI but from 2.2 version.

Is there any way to get json graph data with 2.1?

Thanks.